# Определение самых больших групп пикселей opencv, pytesseract

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract

Есть изображение [image: введите сюда описание изображения]. В нём нужно оставить самые большие группы пикселей, т.е силуэты букв. В дальнейшем из "отфильтрованного" изображения будет изыматься текст с помощью библиотеки `pytesseract` методом `pytesseract.image_to_string()`. Изображение получено с помощью данного кода:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import Image

img = cv2.imread("image.png")
crop_img = img[0:90, 55:150]
gray = cv2.cvtColor(crop_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 240, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
crop_img[thresh != 255] = 0

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (1, 1))
erosion = cv2.erode(crop_img, kernel, iterations = 2)

cv2.imwrite("CROP.jpg",erosion)
```

На input шло данное изображение [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заодно, возможно, предложите более действенный способ получения текста с этого изображения)?